# Bootstrap Markdown (CodeIgniter 2)

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, markdown

I am using [Bootstrap Markdown](http://toopay.github.io/bootstrap-markdown/) for my project powered by CodeIgniter 2.

When I use it on a textarea, it does the markup, the preview and all buttons work perfectly.

The only problem I have is when I submit the form, it does not use the HTML Markup, but the Markdown.

e.g. When I write

```
Text
**Bold**
Else
```

and then click on `Preview` it does the Preview (I see the HTML markup). But as soon as I submit the form, it saves it as

```
Text
**Bold**
Else
```

Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance.